# Capacity of ctangle exceeded

Tags: literate-programming

I'm interested in looking at (and maybe modifying) the code in MetaFont/MetaPost.

To generate their C code, I applied ctangle to mp.w, and got an error message saying "token capacity exceeded". Running ctangle on smaller files works OK, so I think the problem is just that mp.w is too big.

Are there any pre-built versions of ctangle with larger capacity ?

If I have to build one myself, which parameters should I adjust ? I see these:

```
max_bytes 1000000   /* number of bytes in identifiers, index entries, & section names
max_toks 1000000    /* number of bytes in compressed \CEE/ code */
max_names 10239     /* number of identifiers, strings, section names;
max_texts 10239     /* number of replacement texts, must be less than 10240 */
hash_size 8501      /* should be prime; used in |"common.w"| */
longest_name 10000  /* section names shouldn't be longer than this */
stack_size 50       /* number of simultaneous levels of macro expansion */
buf_size 1000       /* for \.{CWEAVE} and \.{CTANGLE} */
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to answer my own question, but I discovered that the ctangle in the MikTex distribution has the capacity needed to handle mp.w.